# Android VPN service's policy based routing relative to iptables (specific behavior question, android 5.0, 5.1)

Tags: security, vpn, services, router, iptables

Background:
Several phones, different firmwares

Elephone p7000, Android 5.0 based rom

Xiaomi redmi note 2, three different roms (5.1 based Cyaonogen, 5.0 based AOSP derivative)

Rooted.

Installed a VPN app (Shadowsocks, OpenVPN, reproduces on both)

Now added an iptables rule like that

*iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT ! -o tun0 -p all -m owner --uid-owner [uid of an app] -j REJECT*

**1)**
On elephone p7000 (android 5.0) and Redmi Note 2 (Cyanogen, A 5.1) the app now works only if VPN is connected

**2)**
On Redmi Note 2 (AOSP 5.0 based ROM) app no longer works whether VPN connected or not.

Questions:

a)
where does android VPN service's policy based routing stuff "normally" happen relative to [netfilter packet flow](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) ?

b)
Which one of the aforementioned behaviors is the "normal" android behavior?

c)
Is there a way (a clever ip rule trick, perhaps) to re-implement behavior 1 on systems exhibiting behavior 2?

Hope I was clear (not native speaker)

Thank you